# Photonic devices assembly (Passive optical alignment) online lectures/books

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, laser

I started a new internship recently in a photonic devices company, I have a background in physics but not that much in optics (I know the basics). So there are a lot of terms that I don't understand such as "passive/active optical alignment". I searched online for lectures to get an introduction for photonic devices assembly but I failed to find something useful.
Does anyone have any ideas where I could find online lectures, books or references on photonic devices assembly?

Comment: the easiest way should be to ask an older colleague for advice on learning material. New to a job thats usual.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing you learn on the job, not from a class or book. Learning stuff like this is one of the most valuable benefits of doing an internship.

Active alignment means you monitor the optical signal during the process and adjust the alignment to optimize the performance. For example, adjust a lens position to maximize the optical power delivered to a photodiode.

Passive alignment means using some other method, like a mechanical stop or a vision system to control the alignment process.